# Eclipse is running as applet not application. How do i go back?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, applet

I'm not exactly sure what i changed, but my project is running as an applet and not an application anymore so therefore its trash. How do i go back to application? You'd think there would be something on the internet for this..

Comment: Please explain more as what you are saying does not make sense.

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood In Eclipse IDE, when i press the "run" button at the top. Instead of running it as an application like normal, it runs it as an "applet". With "Applet View" instead of a regular application. I dont know how to make it clearer than that. When i press "Run as..." there are no options.

Answer (score 0):

when you right click to do "Run as ..." you should also see "Run Configurations" - click on this.  On the left side you will see Applets, delete what is below this.

Comment: I deleted that, but it still runs as applet. The project isnt under applications anymore. Is there a way to add it to that?

Comment: Nevermind i just created a new project and copied my classes into that. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @RyanBrady: Post somewhere a screen shot of your IDE project structure  and show us.